# How to define SOCKET structures in ctypes?

Tags: bluetooth, ctypes, winsock2, python-2.5, pythonce

I am trying to use ctypes to create a bluetooth socket in python2.5 ( actaully PythonCE, no higher version available). I am not sure how to defined the returned SOCKET structure by `socket (AF_BT, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM)` in ctypes.

```
winsock2.h
#define WSAAPI                  FAR PASCAL
...
#if INCL_WINSOCK_API_TYPEDEFS
typedef
SOCKET
(WSAAPI * LPFN_SOCKET)(
    IN int af,
    IN int type,
    IN int protocol
    );
#endif /* INCL_WINSOCK_API_TYPEDEFS */
```

also I defeined WSDATA as below. Being new to C++ and ctypes, I am not sure if its right.

```
#typedef struct WSAData {
class WSADATA( Structure ):
    __fields__ = [
        ( 'wVersion', w.WORD),      #  WORD wVersion;
        ('wHighVersion', w.WORD),   #  WORD wHighVersion;
        ('szDescription', w.CHAR * 10 ),   # char szDescription[WSADESCRIPTION_LEN+1]; Null-terminated ASCII string into which the Ws2_32.dll copies a description of the Windows Sockets implementation. The text (up to 256 characters in length) 
        ('szSystemStatus', w.CHAR * 10 ),  # char  szSystemStatus[WSASYS_STATUS_LEN+1]; Null-terminated ASCII string into which the WSs2_32.dll copies relevant status or configuration information.
        ('iMaxSockets', w.USHORT),   #  unsigned short iMaxSockets;  Ignored for Winsock 2.0 
        ('iMaxUdpDg', w.USHORT),     #  unsigned short iMaxUdpDg; Ignored for Winsock 2.0 and later
        ('lpVendorInfo', w.CHAR)     #  char FAR* lpVendorInfo;  ignored for winsock v2 
    ]
#} WSADATA, *LPWSADATA;
```

I want to use the socket interface, it seems easier to control than the vcom way (I doubt if the virtual com port will ever work on my handheld.), but the winsock structures are so complicated... Is there any way to wrap them up and pass them like blackboxes. these descriptors are not supposed to be operated in python anyway.

Comment: I don't know how to build for *WinCE*, neither if the *VStudio* header files match with the regular ones, but I see a problem in your  `WSADATA` definition. Wouldn't it be possible to use *Python* wrappers (the socket module) instead of duplicating all those structs?

Comment: Hi, it's a bluetooth socket, py2 socket moudle doesn't seem to support this type. I guess I should try `SOCKET=c_void_p` ? I am creating all the follwing structs before I can test if this works... I will update this question, after some test. By problem do you mean the lpVendorInfo pointer? I am lucy, it's ignored,I can get winsocks version. also, I don't know what is the FAR stand for, these struct defs  seem to have many FARs...

Comment: *SOCKET* is `unsigned long long` (8 bytes). If you'd like, I could define the structure for you (I'll place the *C* definition and the *Python* wrapper so you could get an idea of how to do it), but that can't fit in a comment only in an answer. Also this structure is only the 1st step, there are probably many more that you need to define. Y oucould search for a *Python* module that deals with *BT*, there must be some.

Comment: Hi, I tried ulonglong, it didn't work. then I figure this WinCE stuff is more constraint, I tried ulong. then it worked. Now I can send text to the Printer. there still is some encoding and stability issue. If I run the same script 3 time in the same python instance via execfile, it always crash python with some windows error message. But it's close. Thank you for the help. If you want to post it as answer, I will accept it,

Comment: Btw, how did you know its ulonglong ? Was this LPFN_SOCKET interpreted as long pointer to socket filename or sth ?

Comment: I looked into *VStudio* include files. All the constants and structures should be defined there (*C*). In *Python*, `SOCKET` should be `ctypes.c_ulonglong`. Types should be consistent with the ones from regular *Win*. `LPFN_SOCKET` is a pointer to a function that accepts 3 int args and returns a `SOCKET`. It's https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740506%28v=vs.140%29.aspx.